# monodroid licensing question

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Can anyone explain what the feature "Enterprise deployment (Deployments larger than 100 devices)" give you?

Does the professional edition only allow you to ship product to less than 100 devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The professional edition target developer that want to distribute their applications through the Apple AppStore ([iOS Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) members).

The Enterprise Edition targets developers that want to distribute their applications as in-house apps ([iOS Enterprise Developer Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) members).

The "100 devices" number comes from the fact that the standard iOS Developer Program also supports in-house distribution of the application, but it allows in-house deployment for up to 100 devices only.

So, yes, if you are targeting in-house deployment, the MonoTouch Professional Edition will limit you to 100 devices. To support more, you need the Enterprise Edition.

However, if you are targeting AppStore distribution, the Professional Edition should be enough for you. There is no limitation on the number of devices you can deploy to through the AppStore.

Comment: Thank you.  That explains it.

Comment: What does iOS/MonoTouch have to do with Monodroid?

Comment: The MonoDroid licensing follows the same model as MonoTouch. But yes, that is a good catch - when I answered the question, I was thinking MonoTouch, not MonoDroid.

Comment: Yeah, but there is no iOS Enterprise Developer Program equivalent in Android world, is it? So, it is still not clear what exactly is Enterprise Deployment in Monodroid world. :-)

Comment: @Miha Markic - there isn't one by Google. However, as far as the MonoDroid licensing goes, Novell (and now Xamarin) most likely stick to the same terms as MonoTouch, in order to make it the least confusing. That's what I'd do, if I was trying to get both iOS and Android developers to be my clients. Simplicity rules.

Comment: Looks like this then: it *allows* you to distribute your application via non-public markets. In other words, I guess, it forbids you to distribute your app via non-public markets with Pro license.